# Joining 2 streams from same object in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects of class `A` defined as below:

```
class A {
    private Set<String> sOne;
    private Set<String> sTwo;
    // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Now I would like to create a stream which contains elements of both `sOne` and `stwo`. Is there a way to do it in Java 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine them using:

```
List<A> aList = ...;

Stream<String> stream = aList.stream()
                             .flatMap(a -> Stream.concat(
                                      a.getsOne().stream(), 
                                      a.getsTwo().stream())
                              );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Stream.concat(sOne.stream(), sTwo.stream())
```

You should just be aware that this drops some characteristics IIRC in some cases.

Comment: something like `Stream<String> joinedStream = listOfA.stream().flatMap(a -> Stream.concat(a.getSOne().stream(), a.getSTwo().stream()));` to match the question requirement of list of `A`.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I was aware of this but I was hoping if there is a way to do this in the fluent way eg. `listOfA.stream().` something after this. This was a simple example. In my case, I am getting this `listOfA` after a series of operations.

Comment: @Naman Nice one. Looks like yours is the simplest way of doing this.

Comment: @Holger indeed... Will remove the comment

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to already mentioned [`Stream::concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) is the [`Stream::of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-):

```
Stream.of(sOne.stream(), sTwo.stream())
      .flatMap(Function.identity())
      ...
```

This requires to flatten the structure unless you wish to work with `Stream<Stream<T>>` or a stream of any collection `Stream<Collection<T>>`.